# Cleaning up extra space in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I'm look for an effective way to remove unwanted space in a string. Right down to the point, this is the string from HTML i'm dealing with:

```
<h1 class="notranslate" data-se="item-name">
                Evil Skeptic 
            </h1>
```

It appears on [this page](http://www.roblox.com/Evil-Skeptic-item?id=110336757). So if you run this in console:

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('notranslate')[1].innerHTML);
```

it would alert a strange looking text, which is unwanted. Is there an effective way to remove this extra spacing?

Comment: `String.prototype.trim`

Comment: [1] is the second element. Are you sure you don't want [0]?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser/version, `String.prototype` might have a `trim` method you can use right out of the box:

```
str.trim();
```

Otherwise, if you're using jQuery, it has a `trim` method (and other libraries do as well):

```
$.trim(str);
```

Finally, if neither of those options works, you could implement one yourself. Try something like this:

```
function trim(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
}
```

Comment: Im using jquery, so the `$.trim(str);` works perfectly!

Comment: @Alex: Prefer `str.trim()` if you’re using `getElementsByClassName`; `getElementsByClassName` support pretty much guarantees `String.prototype.trim`.

Comment: @minitech: I'm actually using jquery for my script but I posted that because it's simpler to see and i knew i'de get an answer faster :)

Comment: @Alex: Fair enough! :D